# How can upload image Java Spring app with Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I want to upload an image and convert it to a byte[]. Now I can choose image with Vaadin Upload. But the image is not uploaded.

```
imgU = new Upload();
imgU.setCaption("Upload");
gridLayout.addComponent(imgU);
```

What should i do?

Comment: Which version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I have Vaadin 8

Comment: Hi, I just briefly took a look over and found these [Vaadin docs java examples](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/java-examples) and some [github examples](https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/UploadExample.java) maybe you will find it useful. But, basically, it looks like you have to use buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upload will need a `Receiver` to work properly. Then you'll need to provide an *OutputStream* (like *ByteArrayOutputStream*) and then in the succeeded listener you can read the bytes from your buffer. I just released [a blog entry](https://vaadin.com/blog/uploads-and-downloads-inputs-and-outputs) that explains this more detailed.

For your use case, I'd suggest to use *UploadField* or *ImagePreviewField* component from the [EasyUploads add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/easyuploads). Using those you can also Binder, for example if you are storing the image data to a JPA entity, or just use `getValue()` method to return the byte[] in value change listener.

Comment: Then I guess [github example](https://github.com/vaadin/book-examples/blob/master/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/UploadExample.java) will help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener which then handles the received file.

Look here for more details and examples: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/java-examples

It will then look like this:

```
upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
    Component component = createComponent(event.getMIMEType(),
            event.getFileName(), buffer.getInputStream());
    showOutput(event.getFileName(), component, output);
});
```

Comment: But i cant define MemoryBuffer

Comment: The MemoryBuffer helper class was introduced in Vaadin 10.